# How do I change the input background color and text color when a specific value is saved?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, user-input

This is my first time using the Stack overflow website, so apologies if anything is unclear or missing. If you'd like to see a particular part of my code, let me know.

I wrote my PHP code (as good as I can, forgive me if it's not always best practice) according to the MVC model (OOP) and use phpMyAdmin to save my data.

In my example photo's you can see that I have input fields (within a table including a form).
Within the input fields you can enter a number from 4 to 10. As you can see in the pictures, each number has its own text color and background color when you type it (because of the oninput event).

However, when I press Enter and the numbers are saved, the specific text color and background color are gone.

[this is what I would like to see also when the data is saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijhFZ.png)
[here is another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XJvZ.png)
[this is what you see when the numbers are saved and this is what I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBD8t.png)

Here is an example of my code. It's just one of the table cells in which you can input a number and save it in my database by pressing the Enter key(I made a JavaScript function for this).

```
<td id="color1" class="score">
    <input type="number" min="4" max="10" name="p_1_1" id="p_1_1" value="
    <?php $pointsData->fetchPoint1_1($_SESSION["userid"]); ?>" oninput="changeColor(this.value)"></input>
</td>
```

If someone can explain how to keep the colors when data is stored in the database like in the first two pictures, that would be amazing!

Kind regards, Robin

I tried so many things, I tried if statements in a few ways with PHP code and also with making a Javascript function. For example I wrote some if, if esle, if else, etc. statements where I assigned the specific number in between the parentheses. I then echo out the input line and
include the style attribute inside the input element. Give different value's for the background color and text color. Unfortunatly it then doesn't show the data anymore, because the code to show and edit the data PHP code. And because that is then inside the value of the input element, it is PHP code nested inside HTML code, nested inside PHP code. If it is possible to nest like this, I couldn't figure out how.

I'm sorry if this is very vage, I also deleted all the code I tried that didn'nt work, so I can't show you.

Comment: `$pointsData->fetchPoint1_1($_SESSION["userid"])` what does this return if the input has not yet been saved by the user?  zero?  empty string?  What does the function changeColor look like?

Comment: I'm no JS expert, but it looks like you're only setting the color when the input changes. You should trigger the color change on page load or whichever event JS devs are triggering things on these days.

Comment: is **fetchPoint1_1** a function that echoes anything? Because your PHP doesn't actually echo the output of that value. you can try **<?php echo** if it doesn't have its own echo value.

Comment: on page load you just need to trigger the function once for all the numbers as input has the values but it want trigger the change colour when page loads with the value from db

Comment: Thank you all for responding so quickly, the code below from James was exactly what I needed. It feels like magic that it works now. You are like wizards and I am a sorceress in training :D

Answer (score 5):

One way is to trigger that same `changeColor` function on every appropriate input when the page first loads.

You might need to prevent changeColor from being called if the value of the input has not yet been entered, by testing what inp.value is and reacting appropriately.  Can't tell from your question what the specifics should be.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".score input");
  for (let inp of inputs) {
    changeColor.call(inp, inp.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe... it works! Thank you so incredibly much!!!! Have a nice evening :)